# Transforming a simple excel function into pandas df

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, function

I'm quite a beginner in python and I try to convert an excel sheet into a pandas dataframe.

I have following if statement in excel:
=IF(MOD(F183,2)=1, "PAUSE", "BREAK")

The column F183 represents 8 quarters: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I started to define a function and then to put it into the dataframe with .apply, but I'm quite struggling with setting up the function in the first place. That's what I have so far:

```
def pause(i):
    i = df['Quarter']
    if i.mod(2) == 1:
        return "PAUSE"
    else: 
        return "BREAK"
```

When I call the function with e.g. pause(2), I get a value error.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: If you're using `apply`, then pandas is HANDING you the value.  You don't have to look it up.  Skip the `i = df['Quarter']` line.  Are you using `apply` on the `'Quarter'` column?

Comment: I wanted to use the values from the "Quarter" column for the function and then put the result into a new column in the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could this - where column F in your spreadsheet is represented by df['Quarter']

```
import numpy as np
df['PAUSE_BREAK']=np.where(df['Quarter']%2==0,'BREAK','PAUSE')
```

Edit: I would slightly edit the function to take on values only, then apply 'map' that maps that function to each element of the series df['Quarters']

```
def pause(i):
    if i%2 == 1:
        return "PAUSE"
    else: 
        return "BREAK"

df.Quarter.map(pause)
```

Edit2: with the apply function, I would pass in this lambda function - seems to work as well

```
df.apply(lambda row:'PAUSE' if row['Quarter']%2==1 else 'BREAK',axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, but...  They were passing this function to `.apply`, and apply does not present row numbers.

Comment: Oh I skipped that part of the description...my bad..but maybe there is no need to use apply then ?

Comment: it was more that I wanted to use the function to create a new column with these values and I thought that it's done via apply

Comment: I edited the response :p 3 ways of handling it...but I reckon the lambda function by the end is what you want - if you want to use apply instead of the others